# How to result invalid LogicalExpression in Dafny?

Tags: methods, dafny

Consider the following dafny function below:

```
function method unpair(n: nat): (nat, nat)
{
  var x,y :| n == (x+y)*(x+y+1)/2 + y;
  return (x,y)
}
```

Given some natural number n, I would like to identify 2 natural numbers x and y which satisfy the equation (x+y)*(x+y+1)/2 + y. This is possible using Cantor's Pairing Function, but not sure I have the correct syntax for it, as dafny is throwing an error: "invalid LogicalExpression" on the return line. How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `function method` is (perhaps confusingly) a `function`, with the only difference being that it is allowed to be called from non-ghost contexts. In any `function` (including `function method`s), we don't need to say `return` in Dafny. Instead, the body of the function is just the expression we want to return. So you should write

```
function method unpair(n: nat): (nat, nat)
{
  var x,y :| n == (x+y)*(x+y+1)/2 + y;
  (x,y)
}
```

At this point, you have a syntactically valid function.

Dafny then complains about several semantic issues. First, there are a few errors about "not satisfying the constraints of type `nat`". You can fix those by explicitly declaring `x` and `y` to have type `nat`, like this:

```
function method unpair(n: nat): (nat, nat)
{
  var x:nat,y:nat :| n == (x+y)*(x+y+1)/2 + y;
  (x,y)
}
```

At this point, Dafny reports one additional error, which is that it cannot prove that there always exist such an `x` and `y`. This is a more fundamental problem. You will need to convince Dafny (probably using a separate lemma) that such numbers always exist.